# Is there an example security.import.xml for artifactory documented anywhere?

Tags: docker, artifactory

So I am trying to pre-configure an Artifactory docker image with some permissions on some standard repos.

I have been able to pre-configure LDAP settings, some groups, and permissions. But it seems the permissions use a mask to set what can be done.

Example:

```
<acl>
        <permissionTarget>
            <name>Deployer</name>
            <repoKeys>
                <string>ANY LOCAL</string>
            </repoKeys>
            <includes>
                <string>**</string>
            </includes>
            <excludes/>
        </permissionTarget>
        <aces>
            <ace>
                <principal>sec_alm_deployers</principal>
                <group>true</group>
                <mask>3</mask>
            </ace>
        </aces>
        <updatedBy>_system_</updatedBy>
    </acl>
```

But I don't know what are valid mask values?

Does anyone know of any example security.import.xml files for Artifactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain the use of `security.import.xml`.
Assuming you have one Artifactory call it Site A with users, groups and permission created. Now you want to bring up Artifactory Site B with all this users, groups and permission created in Artifactory Site A.

To do that you need to follow this simple steps:

1. Get Security Configuration Descriptor of Artifactory Site A using REST API/UI [LinkToWiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-SecurityConfigurationDescriptor)
2. Rename it to `security.import.xml` and pass it to `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/` directory of Artifactory Site B [LinkToWiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-BootstrappingtheSecurityConfiguration)
3. Start Artifactory Site B.

I hope this will help you understand how you can create your own `security.import.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find an example `security.import.xml`. I don't think you're meant to create them by hand: I think you're supposed to configure an Artifactory instance how you'd like, and then take the xml from that instance so you can use it elsewhere.

I do know the valid mask values:

- `1`: Read
- `2`: Deploy/Cache
- `4`: Annotate (create/delete/modify artifact properties)
- `8`: Delete/Overwrite
- `16`: Manage (change permission settings)

The mask is additive, so if you want multiple of these in a permission, you add them together. For instance, if you want read, deploy, and delete, it would be `1 + 2 + 8`, so the mask is `11`.